# Accessing Gii with active urlManager

Tags: php, yii, gii, yii-url-manager

I am using Yii framework version 1.1.14 and all that I want is to access Yii code generator Gii. It is possible by typing

```
http://somegoodapp123/index.php?r=gii
```

but if I activate urlManager, it is not possible.
Could you please help me, how to access Gii in url with active urlManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `gii` by simply changing your url to the following one

```
http://somegoodapp123/index.php/gii
```